# Как можно ускорить выполнение программы. Не хватает пары сотен секунд

Tags: python

Рассмотрим целочисленный массив ***a*** длины ***n***. Назовём расстоянием от индекса ***i*** до множества индексов ***S*** величину ***dist(i,S)=∑_j∈S|a_i−a_j|***. Зафиксируем целое число ***k***. Рассмотрим функцию ***f(i)=min dist(i,S)***, где минимум берётся по множествам ***S*** размера ***k***, не содержащим индекс ***i***. Определите значение ***f(i)*** для всех ***i*** от 1 до ***n***.

Пример ввода:
5 3
3 2 5 1 2

В первой строке заданы два целых числа ***n*** и ***k*** (2≤***n***≤300000, 1≤***k***<***n***), описанные в условии. Во второй строке содержится ***n*** целых чисел ***ai*** (1≤***a_i***≤10^9) — элементы массива ***a***.

Пример вывода:
4 2 8 4 2

Алгоритм работы примерно следующий:

К каждому элементу массива ищем ***k*** ближайших по значению элемента (сам элемент не учитывается). Получаем сумму модулей разницы найденного и исходного.

```
def nearest(lst, target):
    return min(lst, key=lambda x: abs(x - target))


def func(k, arr):
    result = ''
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        f = 0
        arr_copy = arr.copy()
        arr_copy.pop(i)
        for j in range(k):
            num = nearest(arr_copy, arr[i])
            if num in arr_copy:
                f += abs(arr[i] - num)
                arr_copy.remove(num)
        result += str(f) + ' '
    return result


def main():
    f = input().split()
    s = map(int, input().split())
    print(func(int(f[1]), list(s)))
```

Пробовал обходить алгоритм при встрече высчитанного элемента - результатов в плане сокращения времени не дало.

Comment: Сложность вашего алгоритма - кубическая `O(n*k*3n)`. Как минимум можно за за `O(n*k)`. Плюс копирование списка - это довольно времязатратная процедура.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если идти окном размером k по отсортированному списку, должно быть значительно быстрее.

```
import random

def func(k, arr):
    lst = sorted(arr)
    d = {}
    _se = sum(lst[:k])
    for i in range(len(lst)-k):
        _se += lst[i+k]
        sb, se = 0, _se
        for p in range(k+1):
            v = lst[i+p]
            se -= v
            sum_dist = (p*v - sb) + (se - (k-p)*v)
            if v not in d or sum_dist < d[v]:
                d[v] = sum_dist
            sb += v
        _se -= lst[i]

    return [str(d[v]) for v in arr]


k = 300
s = random.sample(range(1, 10**9 + 1), 30000)
print(" ".join(func(k, s)))
```

Данная выборка (300 из 30000) обработалась за 5.11 сек. Вариант от @ДимаВиноградов - за 274.14 секунды. Оригинальная функция дала ответ за ... *(прошло более получаса - всё ещё думает)*.

---

Вариант за линейное время:

```
def func(k, arr):
    lst = sorted(arr)
    d = {}
    sb, se = 0, sum(lst[:k+1])
    b, ll = 0, len(lst)
    for i,v in enumerate(lst):
        se -= v
        d[v] = (i-b)*v*2 - sb + se - k*v
        while b < i and b+k+1 < ll:
            sum_dist = (i-b-1)*v*2 - sb + lst[b] + se + lst[b+k+1] - k*v
            if sum_dist > d[v]:
                break
            d[v] = sum_dist
            sb -= lst[b]
            b += 1
            se += lst[b+k]
        sb += v

    return [str(d[v]) for v in arr]
```

При любом k на списке в 300 тыс элементов укладывается в пару секунд. Принцип почти тот же, только окно движется только вправо, без возврата и без полного перебора k дистанций для каждого элемента. Так что по сути работает за O(n).

Comment: Тест, к сожалению, все равно не прошло. Привести его не могу - он скрыт.

Comment: @matvuric Добавил ещё вариант, который на пару-тройку порядков быстрее.

Comment: Почему вы говорите про линейное время, если только сортировка n log(n)?

Answer (score 0):

на больших данных вроде бы работает быстрее. Много тестов не делал.

```
from heapq import nsmallest
from copy import copy

def func_of(k, list_of):
    result = []
    for i, m in enumerate(list_of):
        new_list = copy(list_of)
        new_list.pop(i)
        nearest = nsmallest(k, new_list, key=lambda x: abs(x - m))
        sum_of = sum([abs(m - j) for j in nearest])
        result.append(sum_of)
    return ' '.join(map(str, result))
```

взамен обеих ваших функций.